# Regex Match ALL Dynamic string words to data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, custom-data-attribute

Is it possible to have a dynamically generated string

```
var string= "a,b,c";
```

and make a regex out of that that accepts any of the strings words as accepted matches?

```
regExApproved = new RegExp(string, 'ig');
```

So that we can search a data-attribute of an element and show it if it has any of the accepted matches in the attribute

```
$(this).attr("data-payment").match(regExApproved)
```

The problem im facing is the regex takes the whole string and makes that the only match case.
I need the regex to break the string down and accept ANY word in it as a match

Is this possible?
I do not want to use a forloop and make LOTS of different regex Matches for each word in the string but maybe I have to?

Comment: ***I need the regex to break the string down and accept ANY word in it as a match***. You want to break the string based on what? How are you defining words here?

Comment: words are all groups seperated by comma

Comment: It's just comma or it can be space character or any other separator?

Comment: The words are seperated with comma and space like word, word,

Comment: Ok, I got it, please check my answer below, I gave a solution and made a sample demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using

```
var regExApproved = new RegExp(string.split(",").map(x => x.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')).join('|'), 'i');
```

Then, to check if a regex matches a string, it makes more sense to use `RegExp#test` method:

```
regExApproved.test($(this).attr("data-payment"))
```

Notes:

- `.split(",")` - splits into comma-separated chunks
- `.map(x => x.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&'))` (or `.map(function(x) return x.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&'); })`) - [escapes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript) the alternatives
- `.join('|')` creates the final alternation pattern.

**Edit**

It seems that your `string` is an array of values. In that case, use

```js
var string= ['visa','mastercard'];
var regExApproved = new RegExp(string.join('|'), 'i');
// If the items must be matched as whole words:
// var regExApproved = new RegExp('\\b(?:' + string.join('|') + ')\\b', 'i');
// If the array items contain special chars:
// var regExApproved = new RegExp(string.map(x => x.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')).join('|'), 'i');
console.log(regExApproved.test("There is MasterCard here"));
```

Comment: Thanks but it this Regex which is what is produced :
    /\b(["visa"|"mastercard"])\b/gi


Doesnt Match my data-value:
    "all, visa, mastercard, ideal, entropay"

Comment: @ChrisCullen What is your real input string? I doubt it is a string, it looks as if your `string` is in fact an *array*. Just do not use `.split(",")` then, omit this command. Try `new RegExp(string.map(x => x.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')).join('|'), 'i')`. There may be other adjustments to code required depending on what you are doing with the regex (replace or match).

Comment: @ChrisCullen I added several solutions. All are based on a single regex that is created once dynamically and only 1 regex test operation is required to check if any is present in the string.

Comment: Thankyou wiktor.
Here is the string:
     Object.values = function(object) {
  var values = [];
  for(var property in object) {
    values.push(object[property]);
  }
  return values;
}
 var val = Object.values(checkboxes);
  var string = JSON.stringify(val);

AS you can see string is a stringifed object.
When I tried to use your new regEx it said string.map is not a function

Comment: @ChrisCullen Why stringify it then? If it is an array, why not pass the `val` with the array of strings to the RegExp constructor?

Comment: Stribizew 
I simply used val instead of the stringified string and I think it may actually work!

Answer (score 1):

If your `string` is a list of comma-separated words, you can split it by comma then use a combination of `Array` methods to check if any `word` is matched inside the test string.

This is how should be your code:

```
string.split(",").map(s => new RegExp('\\b' + s + '\\b')).some(r => $(this).attr("data-payment").match(r))
```

Where we have:

- `string.split(",")` to split the `string` by comma.
- `.map(s => new RegExp('\\b' + s + '\\b'))` to return a relevant `regex` for each word in the `string` using word-boundary.
- `.some(r => $(this).attr("data-payment").match(r))` to check if our `string` matches any one of the created regexes.

**Demo:**

```js
var string = "is,dog,car";

let str = "this is just a test";

if (string.split(",").map(s => new RegExp('\\b' + s + '\\b')).some(r => str.match(r))) {
  console.log("Matched");
}
```